# .NET Core 6 - WPF, MVC and SignalR

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an WPF app that sends a request to an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app when a button is clicked. The action method in the MVC controller that receives the request, calls a method that runs a long task inside a for loop, and I am trying to use SignalR to update a label in the WPF app with the number of the loop iteration being processed.

The problem: after I click the button, the label does not change at all for the duration of the task, and only when the task ends it changes to show the number of the last iteration.

I guess its a problem with synchronous/asynchronous, but I am a noob at it and still can't seem to understand it...

This is the WPF button handler:

```
private async void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:7036/miHub").Build();
    await connection.StartAsync();
    connection.On<string>("Notify", (str) => { lblProgress.Content = str; });

    //calls mvc controller action 
    string url = "https://localhost:7036/Sincro/procesa";

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
        string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class SincroController : Controller {
    private readonly IHubContext<MiHub> _hubContext;
    
    //ctor
    public SincroController(IHubContext<MiHub> hubContext) {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
    
    public async Task<JsonResult> procesa() {
        await longProcess();
        
        var json = new { foo = "bar" };
        return Json(json);
    }
    
    private async Task<int> longProcess() {
        for(int row=0; row<5000; row++) {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Notify", $"Processing thing {row}");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints in SincroController to ensure the "await _hubContext..." is being hit?

Comment: @JoshNoe: yes, I did that and that line is being hit

Comment: Try moving the `connectionOn` call above the`await connection.StartAsync();` line. If you want it to handle updates as they happen and not after it's done, then the connection probably needs to know about the `connectionOn` logic before you actually call `await connection.StartAsync();`. If you still have issues you may need to look into [Dispatcher.Invoke Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) which is used to update the UI from another thread, which SignalR may be utilizing.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Your SignalR method handler wpf side would need to use the Dispatcher if you're making any UI changes as it often if not always gets invoked on a worker thread.

Comment: I also think @quaabaam is right about the order of operations. Additionally you should put the handler on its own line so you can break there and see if it's getting called. If none of these steps advance the ball id suggest putting an entire reproducible example on GitHub and then I'd take a look. My company's WPF app uses SignalR so I'm more familiar with this topic than anyone would ever want to be. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your longProcess code, the for loop is actually very fast, try `Thread.Sleep(1500);`.

#### Test Result

Optimized test code

[image]

**My Test Result**

[image]

**Your code test result**

[image]

[image]

**Sample Code**

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Invoke Api" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSignalrStatus" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblProgress" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxProgress" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="744" Height="327"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="TextBox Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        HubConnection _connection;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Connect();
        }

        private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //calls mvc controller action 
            string url = "https://localhost:44356/Test/procesa";
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            }
        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"https://localhost:44356/mainHub")
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

            await _connection.StartAsync();

            lblSignalrStatus.Content = "Connection started";

            _connection.On<string>("Notify", OnNotifyHandler);

            _connection.Closed += async (error) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
                await _connection.StartAsync();
            };
        }
        public Func<string, Task> NotifyHandler { get; set; }
        private void OnNotifyHandler(string str) // => NotifyHandler?.Invoke(name);
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                string dtime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "   ";
                lblProgress.Content = dtime + str;
                textBoxProgress.AppendText(dtime + str + "\r\n");
                textBoxProgress.ScrollToEnd();
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I finally found out last night exactly that (but it was too late to update here and was planning to do it today). Even a delay of just 1ms is enough to make it work. Still can`t understand the reason to be honest... (Well I found it out using await Task.Delay(2); instead of Task.Sleep(), but the result seems to be the same). Thanks for taking the time to test it and for the detailed answer.