# Connect to a SignalR Hub using Azure SignalR Service

Tags: azure, winforms, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to create a setup where i have an azure signalr service.

Then i hosts a local server, which is a dotnet core console app which "connects" to the azure signalr service using a connectionstring.

Then i have a client (winforms) which tries to connect to that same azure signalr service using the same connectionstring.

But i get this error: System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.'
when i try to start the client.

I have create a azure signalr service on the azure portal site.

Then I have create C# dotnet core console application that when it runs it adds the azure signalR service using the connectionstring:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(@"Endpoint=<my url>.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=<my accesskey>;Version=1.0;");

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapHub<ChatSampleHub>("/ChatSampleHub");
```

It runs fine and i see on the azure portal site that a server is up and running, when i fire up my console app.

I have a class ChatSampleHub like this:

```
public class ChatSampleHub : Hub
{
    public Task BroadcastMessage(string name, string message) =>
    Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message);

    public Task SendMessage(string message) =>
    Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageReceived", message);

    public Task Echo(string name, string message) =>
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId)
                .SendAsync("echo", name, $"{message} (echo from server)");
}
```

Now i have created a winforms app that i want to call the chathub and broadcast to all other clients.
So far i have this on the client when user clicks on the connect button:

```
private async void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(AzureSignalRConnectionString);
    hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("/ChatSampleHub");

    hubProxy.On<string>("MessageReceived", message =>
    {
        // Handle incoming message
        // This is just an example; you can update your UI or perform any desired action here
        AppendMessageToTextBox(message);
    });

    try
    {
        await hubConnection.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected to Azure SignalR");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to Azure SignalR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The AzureSignalRConnectionString is the same connectionstring i used in my console app.
But when I call the await hubConnection.Start(); I get this error:
System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.'

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why you create a dotnet core console application. From the code, it a self-host web application and connect to azure siganlr service.

Comment: From now, this self-host console web application as siganlr server, and the connections with azure signalr service is [server connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-messages-and-connections#how-connections-are-counted).

Comment: And in your winform application, you should use HubConnectionBuilder to create the client connection. For more details, you can refer [this thread (WPF)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76169443/7687666). The correct url should be the `dotnet core console web application` url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Azure SignalR Service workflow.

[image]

In your scenario, you have used the azure signalr service connection string in dotnet core console application which should be a web application.

The this console application is the `Web App` in my screenshot, and other clients (Javascript or winform(.net core)) should negotiate with this web app and get the security, after that the clients could connect azure signalr service.

Comment: Hi Jason, and thanks alot for your posts. I used the console just as a test to setup a quick solution to see how it worked. I ultimately want to use a Web Api.

When i created the azure signalR service i got a connectionstring. What is the point of that connectionstring if i cant use it in clients to connect to the hub? Or have i misunderstood something?

I dont see in your diagram where that connectionstring is used.

Comment: Hi @duta [Azure signalr connectionstring is only used in web application.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core#add-azure-signalr-to-the-web-app) In my screenshot, it is used in Web App.

Comment: Hi again. 

so if i understand correctly, then i setup my web api to run on localhost. the web api uses the connectionstring to setup the connection with azure signalr service. 

then, in my winforms client, i use the hubConnectionBuilder with the localhost url to create a connection to the hub. And after that i can call the hub from the client?

One of the primary reasons for why i want to use azure signalr service is to utilize signalr to handle my communications between clients and the hub. 
As i understand it then the communication wont use http so there is no callback?

Comment: Hi @duta Yes, the workflow you mentioned is correct.

Comment: @duta The methods inside the hub can push message to client mehtods directly, and the client also can invoke hub method.

Comment: @duta If you have a specific questions, you can post a new thread with asp.net-core-signalr tag, I am willing  to help you.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks. I will try out the solution u suggested and will get back to you tomorrow of how it went. Thanks for now.

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried it and it worked just fine! Many thanks. I have a question regarding security/Authentication and how it works when you call the 


"hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(@"https://localhost:7218/myhub")
    .Build();"


 from the client?
From my end, the users sign into their windows machines and starts up the winforms application. Other than that there are no further authentication. So how does the hub knows that it is a user from my organization?

Comment: @duta Thanks for your reply. For the security/Authentication question, you can check the [link1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) and [link2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi).

Comment: @duta I think this is another issue, you can post a new thread and add `azure-active-directory` tag, then other forum users will help you.